# Improve performance of webpack's CSS compilation

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm trying to move our SASS build from gulp + node-sass to webpack with the sass-loader.

As a reference point, gulp + node-sass 3.2 gives us roughly 2.5-3 second build time.

In webpack, if I use style!raw!sass for loading, I'm looking at 10~ second build, and no sourcemaps (because of the raw loader). If I put the css loader for sourcemaps to work,  the additional parsing makes the build take 20-30 seconds on a good day.

I'm wondering what tricks I can use to improve things. Right now the best I've been able to do is split our sass compilation by having a lot of require(...) from javascript to SASS, which then get concatenated in one file. With -watch option, that allows for some a faux-incremental compile, so after the initial build, it isn't too bad.

I'm wondering if there's something I can do beyond that to make it better. 10x slowdown over gulp + nodesass isn't great, but having 2 build tools isn't great either (webpack works 100% fine for JS, even with massive amount of code)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this great article, about webpack, preprocessors, sourcemaps and build speed:
http://eng.localytics.com/faster-sass-builds-with-webpack/

I am currently using sass-loader with node-sass (and libsass), cssmodules (having separed stylesheets, one for each component/container), inline sourceMaps and HMR. It's taking 2-3 seconds to reload de modified component with updated styles.

You can see here an example of configuration:
https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/webpack/dev.config.js